# Examples in QFT of Eigenvectors of $H$ that are not Eigenvectors with Constant Eigenvalues of $\mathcal{H}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In quantum field theory the Hamiltonian, $H$, is usually written as an integral over a Hamiltonian density, $\mathcal{H}$:
$$H = \int \mathcal{H} \operatorname{d}^3x.$$
It is obvious that any eigenvector of $\mathcal{H}$ that has the same eigenvalue for all $\mathbf{x}$ will be an eigenvector of $H$, but are there states that are an eigenvector of $H$ that have spatially varying eigenvalues of $\mathcal{H}$?

My first guess is that the topological solitons are an example, for example the [soliton solutions to the Sine-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation#Soliton_solutions). Is that correct? Are there any others?

Comment: I got confused by your question. You are aware that $\mathcal{H}$ is an *operator density* which is not an operator and that you have to integrate $\mathcal{H}$ over some domain to obtain a well-defined operator on the Hilbert space, right?

Comment: I had not heard that before. Do you have a link to an explanation for why $\mathcal{H}$ cannot be viewed as an operator that has a parameter in it? Does that objection still hold if I use form $\mathcal{H}\operatorname{d}^3x$?

Comment: This doesn't require explanation since it is one of the Wightman axioms. See axiom 2.4 here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wightman+axioms

Comment: That being said, it may still be possible to formulate the question such that it will make sense, but I don't know how. As I've said, I got confused.

Comment: There is no mention of the Hamiltonian density, or a density of any sort, in that link. The $\mathcal{H}$ there is a reference to the Hilbert space on which the operators are defined. 2.4, in particular, is talking about the ability to approximate the Hilbert space with a Schwartz space.

Comment: I have reworded the question to more accurately reflect what I meant.

Comment: The Wightman axiom 2.4 implies that field operators are operator densities and have to be evaluated on test functions to give Hilbert space operators. The Hamiltonian operator is no exception.

Comment: Do you have a link to a web site, or a recommendation for a textbook, that goes into greater detail on this topic?

Comment: Try "Local Quantum Physics" by Rudolf Haag.